# barrel connectors which guarantee outer contact before inner contact?

Tags: connector

Is there any feature I can look for on a barrel connector to ensure that the outer conductor (the negative terminal in my case) makes contact first before the inner conductor?

I can't seem to find this information, and for the pair we have, it looks like the inner conductor usually makes contact first.

Comment: If you already have one where one is guaranteed to make contact first, can't you just switch polarity in your design?

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing a barrel connector where the order of connections could be guaranteed by design.

Comment: "can't you just switch polarity in your design" -- on an off-the-shelf power supply?!

Comment: Probably not. You should make your circuit (something involving the switch?) immune to the order of connections.

Comment: OK, some context here. This is a 24V PCB. Outer contact is the negative terminal. Some people are using it with 3-terminal wall transformer power supplies where the negative terminal is tied to earth ground (I had no idea that those even existed) and the USB and/or DB9 connectors attach to a desktop PC whose ground connection is tied to earth ground. If the 24V connection makes contact before the ground connection for a sustained amount of time, PFFFFT! components fry.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to consider optoisolating the PC connection.

Comment: I have never seen such a feature that would guarantee one side touches first. You can probably find a connector where the outer has a better chance of touching first, but probably not guaranteed. Ignacio and Spehro are correct that the best route is to fix the actual problem and make it so connection order doesn't matter.

Comment: ...and until a few days ago I thought all commercial low-wattage power supplies were two-terminal floating supplies, so it didn't matter. But that's wrong, and we have a PCB we can't change anytime soon. The BOM is something we could change; I guess for now we just have to advise people to not use grounded-negative power supplies.

Comment: BTW, these details are *contextual only* and should not be taken as part of the question. (the usual XY problem remarks would come out of the woodwork at this point -- don't bother)

Comment: So, when attempting to answer this, can we assume you are able and willing to change the panel jack as well as the plug?

Comment: Sure -- actually in my case it's easier to change the jack than it is the plug (which is built into the power supply), but for the purpose of this question, assume either one can be changed.

Comment: The thing I keep running into is that several plugs have that insulated band around the outside to reasonably ensure that the inner contact is the first one to land. I can't seem to find a combination where the opposite is explicitly true.

Answer (score 1):

In direct answer to your question, I don't think there is. [This](http://www.vetco.net/catalog/images/PH-P375-1.jpg) kind with an all-metal ring around the outside has a chance of working. I'll let you shop for whatever style it is that you need.

[image]

You have an interesting problem. To quote the Wikipedia page:

> RS-232 drivers and receivers must be able to withstand indefinite short circuit to ground or to any voltage level up to ±25 volts.

So, one might guess that a 24V connection would be guaranteed to not cause problems, however it appears that (your?) RS-232 level converter is either non-compliant or non-compliant with power off. Charging your power supply capacitor through protection diodes is probably not conducive to the health of the chip.

The cheapest solution is probably to use a different chip and/or put Schottky diodes  from the output/input to the +/- RS-232 supplies and perhaps 12 TVSs from the output/input to your circuit ground.

If money is no object, then a DC-DC converter on the input power is another solution, or opto-isolate the RS-232 as @Ignacio suggests above.

Comment: thanks but that's not my question.

Comment: @NickJohnson I added that later.